# Angular 2+ and getting data from api to service

Tags: angular

I have in my service functions, thats allows us to get and subscribe data in component

```
private _privateLessonsUrl: string = "http://localhost:3000/api/";
public privateLessons: any[];

getPrivateLessons() : any {
    return this._http.get(this._privateLessonsUrl)
      .map( (response: Response) => response.json() );    
}
```

any component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._privateLessonsService.getPrivateLessons().subscribe(
        responseData => this.privateLessons = responseData
    );
}
```

How to achieve that to store data(download it once on app loading, not subscribing) from that function at initialization and keep it in service as:

```
public privateLessons: any[] = [
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... }
];want to download it once on app loading,
```

Comment: You want to download it once on app loading, or download it everytime component is reloaded?

Comment: I want to download it once on app loading,

Comment: You can create service just for providing loaded data. Then, on app loading, call API once and pass data to service. In this service, you can use Subjects and Observables to get necessary data in components. Do you need an example?

Comment: Yes, I would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

You can create Service to provide necessary data. For example:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Filter } from 'app/model/Filter';

@Injectable()
export class FilterService {

  private filterObject: Filter = null;
  private filterSource = new Subject<Filter>();
  filter = this.filterSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setFilter(newFilter: Filter) {
    this.filterObject = newFilter;
    this.filterSource.next(newFilter);
  }

  getCurrentfilter() {
    return this.filterObject;
  }

}
```

This service lets you to set data (sing setFilter function) and subscribe to this data.
To subscribe to filter, you can do:

```
this.filterService.filter.subscribe(newFilter => {
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
    private _privateLessonsUrl: string = "http://localhost:3000/api/";
    public privateLessons: any[];

    // call this on each component you need the data
    getPrivateLessonsData() : Observable<any> {
      return new Observable.Of(this.privateLessons);
    }

    // call this on App init
    requestPrivateLessons() : any {
      return this._http.get(this._privateLessonsUrl)
        .map( (response: Response) => response.json() );    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component would subscribe to `getPrivateLessons()` without knowing if the data is coming from the api or not. In the service you just check that if `privateLessons` has value, if so, return an Observable of it, else perform request. So your component code stays the same, only modify your service:

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

// ...

public privateLessons: any[];

getPrivateLessons() : any {
  // check if privateLessons has value, if so return the array
  if(this.privateLessons && this.privateLessons.length) {
    return Observable.of(this.privateLessons)
  }
  // privateLessons has no value, perform http-request
  return this._http.get(this._privateLessonsUrl)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    // side effect, store data in local variable
    .do(data => this.privateLessons = data);    
}
```